# CakePHP 2.0 - 2.1, Query different model from controller

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I've got an uploads controller which handles video file formats. In the uploads controller you are able to browse all the videos uploaded and watch them. In the function watch I have a comments element which updates the comments table with the userid (comment left by user that is currently logged in) uploadid (uploaded that is currently being watched) and the comment (comment of the user).

I've got the form working perfectly, however I'm not to sure how I would acquire the information from the comments table, such as the necessary query to be implemented?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your other post [CakePHP Elements not updating table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074897/cakephp-elements-not-updating-table), so I sort of have an idea of your situation.  It seems you are representing comments with your Post model.

You want to query data from your Post model, in your UploadsController, correct?

If your comments table is named `comments`, you need to ensure it is associated to your Post model.  Cake automatically associates Models and database tables if they follow Cake's naming conventions.  But if they are in fact different, you can specify a custom database table for your Post model:

```
<?php
class Post extends AppModel {

    var $useTable = "comments" /*Or whatever you named your comments table*/

    ...
}
?>
```

You also have to ensure the model associations are set up between Post and Upload:

```
Post belongsTo Upload
Upload hasMany Post
```

I noticed you have:

```
Post belongsTo Upload
Upload hasAndBelongsToMany Post
```

Is there a reason why it is HABTM?  HABTM implies that the same Post can belong to many different Uploads.  hasMany implies that a Post can only belong to a single Upload.

Finally, now that the model associations are set up, you can access related models in a controller:

```
<?php
class UploadsController extends AppController {

    ...

    function watch ($id = null) {

        $this->Upload->id = $id;      
        $this->set('uploads', $this->Upload->read());

        /* To get related comments (Posts) */
        $related_comments = $this->Upload->Post->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Upload.id' => $id /* This condition makes it so only associated comments are found */
            )
        ));
        $this->set('comments', $related_comments);
    }

    ...

 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I use the HABTM because if I use hasMany I get an error
Database Error
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'uploadid' in where clause is ambiguous

Using the $related_comments I get the following error;

Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/evolvids/app/Controller/UploadsController.php on line 57
Also in addition I have scrapped the comments table and model and just called it posts, any ideas?

Comment: ok I've created the database error, however (and I remember this been the original reason I used the HABTM) the information echoed from the database is being duplicated 3 times on the page when using the hasMany statement? can't see why this is happening, I've set limit to 1 and thats not made a difference either, any ideas as to why thats happening?

Comment: no worries though, because if I change it to $this->Post instead of $this->Upload->Post it works perfectly! and I kept with the orignal HABTM because of the duplicate entries it makes on the page. thanks for your help though :)